# Adding second parameter to web service URL

Tags: url-parameters

I'm using the following moviefone web service in one of my Android applications:

http://gateway.moviefone.com/

The user enters his zip code, and the following XML data is used to get his nearby movie theaters and movies.

http://www.moviefone.com/search/19087?format=xml

My question is, how do you add the parameter for changing the date of the showtimes? That XML only contains movie information for the current date. The web service gateway page says: *"params: zip/id= count= date=YYYYMMDD"*

I tried adding "date=20120208" to the end of the URL but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `&` to separate multiple parameters:

```
http://www.moviefone.com/search/19087?format=xml&date=20120208
```

Answer (score 3):

Separate parameters with an `&`